# How to properly close a MongoClient connection on a node.js server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, httpserver

I'm trying to write a simple benchmark to test mongodb insertions and queries. It works fine from the browser, but when I try to load it using apache benchmark, the DB seems to crash the connections after a certain amount (around 100-150), even though the MongoDB server itself stays up. 
Here is the benchmark output:

```
ab -n 10000 -c 100 http://127.0.0.1:8888/?action=insert

This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (61)
Total of 100 requests completed
```

MongoDB gets up to around 100-150 connections:

```
2014-11-26T22:21:15.596-0500 [conn116] end connection 127.0.0.1:54583 (136 connections now open)
2014-11-26T22:21:15.598-0500 [conn130] end connection 127.0.0.1:54597 (125 connections now open)
2014-11-26T22:22:05.844-0500 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:44 virt:3128
2014-11-26T22:22:05.844-0500 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):640
2014-11-26T22:22:05.844-0500 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
```

But somewhere between there the node.js server crashes:

```
/Users/rw3iss/Sites/benchmark/node_tests/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:409
          throw err
                ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'collection' of null
    at /Users/rw3iss/Sites/benchmark/node_tests/index.js:37:23
    at /Users/rw3iss/Sites/benchmark/node_tests/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:406:11
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

My index.js file is doing this:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

function test_insert(response) {
    mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/benchmark", function(err, db) {
        var data = { name: 'name', value: 'blah' };
        var collection = db.collection('benchmark');  //**this is line 37**
        collection.insert(data, function(err, docs) {
            response.end("Item inserted.");
        });

        db.close();
    });
}
```

The main point of failure is the DB open operation. node.js server spits out:

```
throw new Error("db object already connecting, open cannot be called multiple times
```

Can anyone help me figure out why? Am I not properly closing the connection after the DB operation?

**Update:** Please see answer.
However, there seems to be an issue with queries being very slow:

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:8888/?action=query
Requests per second:    2.32 [#/sec] (mean)
```

My query code is:

```
function test_query(name, response) {
    var result = [];

    if (client) {
        if (!collection) {
          collection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'benchmark');
        }

        function resultCallback(err, results) {
            if(name != null && results.length > 0)
                response.end(JSON.stringify(results[0]));
            else
                response.end(JSON.stringify(results));
        }

        var data = {};

        if(name != null) {
            data['name'] = name;
            collection.find(data).limit(1).toArray(resultCallback);
        } else {
            collection.find(data).toArray(resultCallback);
        }

    } else {
        // can perform reconnecting and then get collection and call callback
        console.log("Error, can't get connection");
    }
}
```

Why is it acting so slow? I'm setting up the connection as described in the first answer below. Can anyone help?

Comment: You're closing the connection before your async `insert` completes (i.e. calls its callback). But you should be opening the `mongo.connect` connection pool once during startup anyway, not on each insert.

Comment: Thanks, updating with a solution I just found.

Comment: Hmm, there seems to be some issue with querying being very slow during the benchmark. 
ab -n 20 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:8888/?action=query
Requests per second:    2.32 [#/sec] (mean)
Please see the original question at the bottom if you wouldn't mind helping.

Answer (score 0):

As stated from JohnnyHK, I can't open a connection with each query. This is a little different from the PHP paradigm (I'm new to node.js). I  was able to find a solution by performing the connection this way:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var server = new mongodb.Server('localhost', 27017, { auto_reconnect: true });

var client;
var collection;

var benchmarkDb = new mongodb.Db('benchmark', server).open(function (err, c) {
  if (!err) {
    client = c;
    client.on('close', function() {
      client = null; // clear client
      collection = null; // clear old collections
      // connection closed
    });
  } else {
    // error connecting
    console.log("Error connecting to MongoDB", err);
  }
});


function test_insert(response) {
    if (client) {
        if (!collection) {
          collection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'benchmark');
        }

        var data = { name: 'name', value: 'blah' };

        collection.insert(data, function(err, docs) {
            response.end("Item inserted.");
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Error, can't get connection");
    }
}
```

Comment: P.S. node.js is performing MUCH faster than PHP, as expected. I have only done testing on DB inserts with nginx+php, and also node.js+mongodb, but it is orders of magnitude faster (nginx/php around 300 requests per second, node.js/mongodb around 1,000 requests per second), for anyone interested.